# How to get info from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to get `name`, `age`, `salary` from the array `products`.
And can you explain me what is wrong?

```js
var products = [
 {name: 'Коля', age: 30, salary: 400},
 {name: 'Вася', age: 31, salary: 500},
 {name: 'Петя', age: 32, salary: 600},
];

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", funct);


function funct(){
  for( var i = 0; i < products.length; i++ ){
    document.write( " this " + products[i] );
  }
  return;
}
console.log(funct());
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Start</button>
```

Comment: Access it's properties i.e. `products[i].name`

Comment: because you're trying to print the whole object, not the individual properties from it. And JS doesn't know how to do that, because it's an object and not a string or number. Refer to the properties by name e.g. `products[i].name`, or if you don't know in advance what they'll be, loop through them with an inner `foreach` loop

Comment: Satpal and Adyson thank you) i got it

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify property name like `products[i].name` not the whole object:

```js
var products = [
 {name: 'Коля', age: 30, salary: 400},
 {name: 'Вася', age: 31, salary: 500},
 {name: 'Петя', age: 32, salary: 600},
];

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", funct);


function funct(){
  for( var i = 0; i < products.length; i++ ){
    console.log( "name: " + products[i].name );
    console.log( "age: " + products[i].age );
    console.log( "salary: " + products[i].salary );
  }
 
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Start</button>
```